# Update con Textarea y foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, update

Buen día, tengo la siguiente duda con mi consulta.

Estoy mandando un textarea con 3 datos diferentes para actualizar unos campos, el problema esta en que solo me actualiza un dato creo que es el ultimo y los otros dos los deja sin modificar, les dejo la consulta.

Aquí esta mi formulario:

```
<form action="src/UpdRepInd.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                Serial Material
                                <textarea name="InputSalidaRS" id="InputSalidaRS" onChange="salida();" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <select name="rutaRS" id="rutaRS" style="display: none; font-size:12px;" class="form-control">
                                    <option value disabled selected>Siguiente ruta...</option>
                                    <option>AOI - 1</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="StatusRS" class="form-control" value="Salida">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" id="DateTimeRS" name="DateTimeRS" class="form-control" style="display: none;" readonly="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <textarea name="ComentarioRS" id="ComentarioRS" style="font-size: 12px; display: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un comentario..."></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>
                        <p></p>
                        <center>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Guardar</button>
                        </center>
                        </form>
```

Aca llega la informacion (UpRepInd.php):

```
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','reparacion');

$Id=$_POST['InputSalidaRS'];
$IdRC = chop($Id);
$IdRCS = nl2br($IdRC);
$Array_SerialRCS = explode("<br />", $IdRCS);

$StatusRS=$_POST['StatusRS'];
$ComentarioRS=$_POST['ComentarioRS'];
$DateTimeRS=$_POST['DateTimeRS'];
$rutaRS=$_POST['rutaRS'];

    foreach ($Array_SerialRCS as $Id)         // Creamos un bucle foreach
    { 
        $sql="UPDATE reparacion.material SET status='$StatusRS', sigruta='$rutaRS', fechasal='$DateTimeRS', comentario = '$ComentarioRS' WHERE serial='$Id'";
        echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location='../index.php';
    </script>
<?php
    }

?>
```

Estoy teniendo este problema solo con el Update por que tengo esta misma consulta con INSERT, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

MODIFICACIÓN:

Depurando:

**var_dump($Array_SerialRCS);**

```
array(3)    { 
                [0]=> string(25) "28654859BP220123195L04B33" 
                [1]=> string(27) " 28654859BP120123196L04B28" 
                [2]=> string(27) " 28572073AP120122046L03B07" 
            } 

array(3)    { 
                [0]=> string(25) "28654859BP220123195L04B33" 
                [1]=> string(27) " 28654859BP120123196L04B28" 
                [2]=> string(27) " 28572073AP120122046L03B07" 
            } 

array(3)    {   
                [0]=> string(25) "28654859BP220123195L04B33" 
                [1]=> string(27) " 28654859BP120123196L04B28" 
                [2]=> string(27) " 28572073AP120122046L03B07" 
            }
```

Comment: Dentro del `foreach` pon un `echo $sql;` y revisa. Puede que `$Id` sea siempre el mismo valor y por eso se queda actualizado sólo el último del bucle. Otra posible causa es que las primeras dos actualizaciones no ocurran porque violan alguna restricción. Eso podrás descartarlo tratando de ejecutar en el manejador cada una de las consultas que se imprima (en el caso de que efectivamente `$Id` sea diferente en cada iteracción del bucle).

Comment: Ya verifique este mandando diferente $Id y si son diferentes lo unico que te corrijo es que me actualiza el primero, no el ultimo dato que pongo, tambien verifique mi array y si me esta enviando los 3 datos, pero solo el primero me lo modifica.

Comment: Prueba a poner `echo $sql;` dentro del `foreach` y trata de ejecutar cada consulta en el manejador directamente. Puede que aquellas que no se actualizan es porque violan alguna restricción o porque los datos que pasarías en la consulta son los mismos que ya existen en esas filas. Es cuestión de depurar tu código.

Comment: No logro actualizar el ciclo que mando solo el primer dato que, ya proble y la informacio se manda en el ciclo, pero no actualiza los demas verifique la informacion que se mando y toda es correcta. por que probe cada dato en el primero textarea y lo acepta, solo no actuliza los demas.

Comment: No entendí tu último comentario.

Comment: Que al parecer los tipos datos que ingreso son correctos ya que actualiza el primer serial que ingrese en el textarea, pero no recorre los otros datos

Comment: No logro entender en qué punto está tu código ni qué has depurado. Haz un `var_dump($Array_SerialRCS);` y dinos qué muestra. Cuando algo falla debes depurarlo para verificar si los elementos con que estás trabajando tienen los valores/datos correctos.

Comment: Ya modifique el post, con la depuración, solo me manda el mismo dato tres veces, y en el text area metí tres seriales diferentes.

Comment: Me he permitido *identar* (entiéndase ordernar) la salida de tu `var_dump`. Obsérvalo ahora y comprenderás, espero, cuál es el problema. Es lo que te dije en uno de mis comentarios, el dato con el que estás trabajando es el mismo. Tienes un array con tres sub-arrays cuyos datos son duplicados, de modo que no estarías actualizando tres filas, como piensas, sino una misma fila. Entonces debes revisar por qué motivo `$Array_SerialRCS` no se está creando con los datos que esperas.  Eso se llama **depurar el código**, debes aprender a hacerlo y te vas a ahorrar muchos días y horas perdidos.

Comment: Solucione el problema con este respuesta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390248/espacios-en-blanco-en-registros-mysql/390282#390282

Comment: Allí hay otras cosas explicadas que no exponías aquí. El caso aquí es que los datos en `$Array_SerialRCS` parecían ser los mismos. Sea como sea, en vez de usar un textarea para esto deberías pensar en algo más controlable (en un textarea el usuario puede escribir lo que quiera sin ningún control). Y como separador, en vez de los saltos de línea, podrías usar un símbolo como `|`, el punto y coma u otro y luego dividir cada fila por ese símbolo, o usar un formulario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es muy sencilla: Separar directamente cada serial por el (o los) caracter(es) de salto de línea, que pueden ser \r, \n o una combinación de ambos, dependiendo del sistema operativo. Afortunadamente, PHP dispone de la constante PHP_EOL, que almacena el valor correspondiente, declarando la variable solo con explode():

```
<?php
$Array_SerialRCS = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($_POST['SerialR']));
```

Se usa trim() para eliminar posibles espacios o saltos de línea provenientes desde el formulario y, se separan los elementos por la constante PHP_EOL. Por supuesto, esto no evita que el usuario haya introducido otros espacios al inicio o final de cada serie, por lo que conviene alguna validación adicional:

```
foreach ($Array_SerialRCS as $SerialR)         // Creamos un bucle foreach
    {
        // Eliminar posibles espacios en cada serie
        $SerialR = trim($SerialR);
        // ¿Es un valor vacío?
        if(empty($SerialR)) {
            // No procesar
            continue;
        }
        // Ya puedes insertar sin problema
        $sql="INSERT into reparacion.material (serial,npparte,cantidad,costototal,referencia,model,linea,falla,status,comentario,fechaent,rack)
        values ('$SerialR','$npparteR','$cantidadR','$CostoR','$referenciaR','$ModelR','$lineaR','$fallaR','$StatusR','$comentarioR','$DateTimeR','$rackR')";
        echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
```