# Espacios en blanco en registros MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia, estoy generando registros multiples con un foreach, el problema que estoy teniendo es que me esta ingresando registros con espacio en blanco al inicio, no se cual es el problema.

Si ingreso tres registros el primero lo ingresa normal, pero los siguientes dos les asigna un espacio en blanco al inicio, les dejo mi codigo.

```
<?php
    $SerialR=$_POST['SerialR'];
    $SerialRC = chop($SerialR);
    $SerialRCS = nl2br($SerialRC);
    $Array_SerialRCS = explode("<br />", $SerialRCS);

    $npparteR=$_POST['npparteR'];
    $cantidadR=$_POST['cantidadR'];
    $referenciaR=$_POST['referenciaR'];
    $lineaR=$_POST['lineaR'];
    $fallaR=$_POST['fallaR'];
    $comentarioR=$_POST['comentarioR'];
    $DateTimeR=$_POST['DateTimeR'];
    $ModelR=$_POST['ModelR'];
    $StatusR=$_POST['StatusR'];
    $CostoR=$_POST['CostoR'];
    $rackR=$_POST['rackR'];


    // CONSULTA PARA TRAER INFORMACION DE INVENTARIO DE MATERIAL SEriALES 
    $QueryInventory="SELECT * FROM reparacion.material WHERE serial LIKE '%".$_POST['SerialR']."%'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$QueryInventory);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $message = "Material agregado correctamente.";
    $message2 = "El material con el serial ingresado ya existe.";

    if ($_POST['SerialR'] == $row['serial']) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message2');</script>";
    }else{
        foreach ($Array_SerialRCS as $SerialR)         // Creamos un bucle foreach
        { 
            $sql="INSERT into reparacion.material (serial,npparte,cantidad,costototal,referencia,model,linea,falla,status,comentario,fechaent,rack)
            values ('$SerialR','$npparteR','$cantidadR','$CostoR','$referenciaR','$ModelR','$lineaR','$fallaR','$StatusR','$comentarioR','$DateTimeR','$rackR')";
            echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
    }       
?>
```

**Imagen de referencia de registros.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque no usas `trim()`

Comment: Podrías usar el método trim() al recibir los parámetros. Algo así: $cantidadR = trim($_POST['cantidadR']);

Comment: Acabo de usar el trim pero me sigue generando el espacio a partir del segundo registro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El origen de los espacios en blanco es por los saltos de línea:

```
<?php
$SerialR=$_POST['SerialR'];
$SerialRC = chop($SerialR);
$SerialRCS = nl2br($SerialRC);
$Array_SerialRCS = explode("<br />", $SerialRCS);
```

La función [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) no quita los saltos de línea, solo inserta la etiqueta `<br>` o `<br />`, dependiendo del tipo de salida esperada.

La solución es muy sencilla: Separar directamente cada serial por el (o los) caracter(es) de salto de línea, que pueden ser `\r`, `\n` o una combinación de ambos, dependiendo del sistema operativo. Afortunadamente, PHP dispone de la constante *PHP_EOL*, que almacena el valor correspondiente, declarando la variable solo con `explode()`:

```
<?php
$Array_SerialRCS = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($_POST['SerialR']));
```

Se usa `trim()` para eliminar posibles espacios o saltos de línea provenientes desde el formulario y, se separan los elementos por la constante *PHP_EOL*. Por supuesto, esto no evita que el usuario haya introducido otros espacios al inicio o final de cada serie, por lo que conviene alguna validación adicional:

```
    foreach ($Array_SerialRCS as $SerialR)         // Creamos un bucle foreach
    {
        // Eliminar posibles espacios en cada serie
        $SerialR = trim($SerialR);
        // ¿Es un valor vacío?
        if(empty($SerialR)) {
            // No procesar
            continue;
        }
        // Ya puedes insertar sin problema
        $sql="INSERT into reparacion.material (serial,npparte,cantidad,costototal,referencia,model,linea,falla,status,comentario,fechaent,rack)
        values ('$SerialR','$npparteR','$cantidadR','$CostoR','$referenciaR','$ModelR','$lineaR','$fallaR','$StatusR','$comentarioR','$DateTimeR','$rackR')";
        echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono correctamente tu solución, ademas que me ayudaste con una pregunta que tenia abierta con esta misma solución.